# Multiple user interaction using photon in MRTK application

Tags: multiplayer, hololens, photon, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

We are working on an app for Hololens2. In this app multiple users can join a room and can perform different hand movements. Here challenge is, we also need to show hands of the users along with their names.

Need your help in understanding resolution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Photon's methods to instantiate the hand prefab and then use it as a copy for live sharing. You can find hand prefabs in **Mixed Reality Toolkit Foundation->SDK->Features->UX->Prefabs->RiggedHandVisualizer**. Then you need to map the current hand position, rotation to this copy. You can also try to map the hand joints, please refer to [Hand tracking - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#scripting) to get joint data.

For the name, you can ask the user to enter a display name for Photon to use before he joins the room. Then you can create a UI for it and have it display with the hand.